# How to get a count of certain entity per minute in a given dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe that looks like below

```
data = [(datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 10, 7, 49, 7, 118658), u'12.100.90.10', u'100.100.12.1', u'LT_DOWN'),
       (datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 10, 7, 49, 14, 312273), u'12.100.90.10', u'100.100.12.1', u'LT_UP'),
       (datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 10, 7, 49, 21, 535932), u'12.100.90.10', u'100.100.12.1', u'LT_UP'),
       (datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 10, 7, 50, 28, 725961), u'12.100.90.10', u'100.100.12.1', u'PL_DOWN'),
       (datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 10, 7, 50, 32, 450853), u'10.100.80.10', u'10.55.10.1', u'PL_LOW'),
       (datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 10, 7, 51, 32, 450853), u'10.10.80.10', u'10.55.10.1', u'MA_HIGH'),
       (datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 10, 7, 52, 34, 264042), u'10.10.80.10', u'10.55.10.1', u'PL_DOWN')]
```

As you can see there is data getting logged per minute. I have just presented part of the complete data here.

This is how it looks on loading it in pandas

```
                        date         start           end     type
0 2021-02-10 07:49:07.118658  12.100.90.10  100.100.12.1  LT_DOWN
1 2021-02-10 07:49:14.312273  12.100.90.10  100.100.12.1    LT_UP
2 2021-02-10 07:49:21.535932  12.100.90.10  100.100.12.1    LT_UP
3 2021-02-10 07:50:28.725961  12.100.90.10  100.100.12.1  PL_DOWN
4 2021-02-10 07:50:32.450853  10.100.80.10    10.55.10.1   PL_LOW
5 2021-02-10 07:51:32.450853   10.10.80.10    10.55.10.1  MA_HIGH
6 2021-02-10 07:52:34.264042   10.10.80.10    10.55.10.1  PL_DOWN
```

Now what I want is two things

First, get count of each value in `type` per minute and furthermore only first part of `_` split in value should be considered for count. So my final output should be something like this

```
              date LT PL  MA
0 2021-02-10 07:49 3  0   0
1 2021-02-10 07:50 0  2   0
2 2021-02-10 07:51 0  0   1
3 2021-02-10 07:52 0  1   0
```

Second convert any non zero to `True` and zero to `False`. So final output would look like

```
              date LT    PL     MA
0 2021-02-10 07:49 True  False  False
1 2021-02-10 07:50 False True   False
2 2021-02-10 07:51 False False  True
3 2021-02-10 07:52 False True   False
```

Now regarding the first part, I can find the count of each value (split on first part of `_`) on the total Dataframe by doing something like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns = ["date", "start", "end", "type"]
df = df.drop_duplicates()
issue = "LT"
df_check = df[df['type'].str.contains(issue)].groupby(['start', 'end']).size().to_frame('icount').reset_index()
```

But how do I do it on a minute basis and map it to `True` and `False`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the data you provided, last item in `type` is `MA_DOWN`, but in the dataframe and the results it is `PL_DOWN`, I think it was an error on your part. I have considered the dataframe version here.

You can use `pandas.DataFrame.resample` with `pandas.get_dummies`:

```
>>> pd.get_dummies(df['type'].str.extract(r'(\w+)_', expand=False)
                   ).set_index(df['date']).resample('1T').sum()
                     LT  MA  PL
date                           
2021-02-10 07:49:00   3   0   0
2021-02-10 07:50:00   0   0   2
2021-02-10 07:51:00   0   1   0
2021-02-10 07:52:00   0   0   1
```

Then `astype(bool)`:

```
>>> pd.get_dummies(df['type'].str.extract(r'(\w+)_', expand=False)
                   ).set_index(df['date']).resample('1T').sum().astype(bool)

                        LT     MA     PL
date                                    
2021-02-10 07:49:00   True  False  False
2021-02-10 07:50:00  False  False   True
2021-02-10 07:51:00  False   True  False
2021-02-10 07:52:00  False  False   True
```

According to your comments, you can use `pd.crosstab`:

```
>>> pd.crosstab(
       index=df['date'].dt.floor('1min'), 
       columns=[
           df['start'].add('-').add(df['end']).rename('star-end'), 
           df['type'].str.extract(r'(\w+)_', expand=False)
       ], 
       dropna=False
    )

start-end           10.10.80.10-10.55.10.1       10.100.80.10-10.55.10.1       12.100.90.10-100.100.12.1      
type                                    LT MA PL                      LT MA PL                        LT MA PL
date                                                                                                          
2021-02-10 07:49:00                      0  0  0                       0  0  0                         3  0  0
2021-02-10 07:50:00                      0  0  0                       0  0  1                         0  0  1
2021-02-10 07:51:00                      0  1  0                       0  0  0                         0  0  0
2021-02-10 07:52:00                      0  0  1                       0  0  0                         0  0  0
```

Or,

```
>>> pd.crosstab(
       index=df['date'].dt.floor('1min'), 
       columns=[
           df['start'], 
           df['end'], 
           df['type'].str.extract(r'(\w+)_', expand=False)
      ], 
      dropna=False
    )
 
start               10.10.80.10                          10.100.80.10                          12.100.90.10                         
end                  10.55.10.1       100.100.12.1         10.55.10.1       100.100.12.1         10.55.10.1       100.100.12.1      
type                         LT MA PL           LT MA PL           LT MA PL           LT MA PL           LT MA PL           LT MA PL
date                                                                                                                                
2021-02-10 07:49:00           0  0  0            0  0  0            0  0  0            0  0  0            0  0  0            3  0  0
2021-02-10 07:50:00           0  0  0            0  0  0            0  0  1            0  0  0            0  0  0            0  0  1
2021-02-10 07:51:00           0  1  0            0  0  0            0  0  0            0  0  0            0  0  0            0  0  0
2021-02-10 07:52:00           0  0  1            0  0  0            0  0  0            0  0  0            0  0  0            0  0  0
```

Comment: You are right. I am working on multiple data frames so might have pasted one of the variations. Sorry about that. I will accept your answer and thank you.

Comment: hi! I just needed one more help. Is it possible to get this count for every unique pair of `start` and `end` ? So basically the same process remains but I want to know for every unique pair of `start` and `end`, what is count of `LT`, `MA` and `PL` after resampling. Thanks!

Comment: I have posted another question since I am having trouble processing the cross tab Dataframe. Can you take a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66141707/how-to-get-frequency-count-of-column-values-for-each-unique-pair-of-columns-in-p

Comment: did you take a look?

Comment: @SouvikRay I did.