# How to get frequency count of column values for each unique pair of columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe that looks like below

```
data = [(datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 10, 7, 49, 7, 118658), u'12.100.90.10', u'100.100.12.1', u'LT_DOWN'),
       (datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 10, 7, 49, 14, 312273), u'12.100.90.10', u'100.100.12.1', u'LT_UP'),
       (datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 10, 7, 49, 21, 535932), u'12.100.90.10', u'100.100.12.1', u'LT_UP'),
       (datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 10, 7, 50, 28, 725961), u'12.100.90.10', u'100.100.12.1', u'PL_DOWN'),
       (datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 10, 7, 50, 32, 450853), u'10.100.80.10', u'10.55.10.1', u'PL_LOW'),
       (datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 10, 7, 51, 32, 450853), u'10.10.80.10', u'10.55.10.1', u'MA_HIGH'),
       (datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 10, 7, 52, 34, 264042), u'10.10.80.10', u'10.55.10.1', u'PL_DOWN')]
```

As you can see there is data getting logged per minute. I have just presented part of the complete data here.

This is how it looks on loading it in pandas

```
                        date         start           end     type
0 2021-02-10 07:49:07.118658  12.100.90.10  100.100.12.1  LT_DOWN
1 2021-02-10 07:49:14.312273  12.100.90.10  100.100.12.1    LT_UP
2 2021-02-10 07:49:21.535932  12.100.90.10  100.100.12.1    LT_UP
3 2021-02-10 07:50:28.725961  12.100.90.10  100.100.12.1  PL_DOWN
4 2021-02-10 07:50:32.450853  10.100.80.10    10.55.10.1   PL_LOW
5 2021-02-10 07:51:32.450853   10.10.80.10    10.55.10.1  MA_HIGH
6 2021-02-10 07:52:34.264042   10.10.80.10    10.55.10.1  PL_DOWN
```

First, I want to get the count of each value in `type` column on a minute basis (in values for column `type`, only first part of `_` split should be considered for count. So it would look something like

```
          date     LT PL  MA
0 2021-02-10 07:49 3  0   0
1 2021-02-10 07:50 0  2   0
2 2021-02-10 07:51 0  0   1
3 2021-02-10 07:52 0  1   0
```

But the above data doesn't tell for every unique pair of `start` and `end` column values, what is the count for `LT`, `PL`, `MA` (after split on `_`).

Thanks to **@Sayandip Dutta**, he provided the below solution (https://stackoverflow.com/a/66136108/5550284)

```
pd.crosstab(
       index=df['date'].dt.floor('1min'), 
       columns=[
           df['start'].add('-').add(df['end']).rename('star-end'), 
           df['type'].str.extract(r'(\w+)_', expand=False)
       ], 
       dropna=False
)
```

Here is how the dataframe looks like

```
start-end           10.10.80.10-10.55.10.1       10.100.80.10-10.55.10.1       12.100.90.10-100.100.12.1      
type                                    LT MA PL                      LT MA PL                        LT MA PL
date                                                                                                          
2021-02-10 07:49:00                      0  0  0                       0  0  0                         3  0  0
2021-02-10 07:50:00                      0  0  0                       0  0  1                         0  0  1
2021-02-10 07:51:00                      0  1  0                       0  0  0                         0  0  0
2021-02-10 07:52:00                      0  0  1                       0  0  0                         0  0  0
```

So on converting the above to boolean, it looks like below

```
start-end           10.10.80.10-10.55.10.1       10.100.80.10-10.55.10.1       12.100.90.10-100.100.12.1      
type                                     LT     MA     PL                      LT     MA     PL                            LT     MA     PL
date                                                                                                          
2021-02-10 07:49:00                      False  False  False                   False  False  False                         True   False  False
2021-02-10 07:50:00                      False  False  False                   False  False  True                          False  False  True
2021-02-10 07:51:00                      False  True  False                    False  False  False                         False  False  False
2021-02-10 07:52:00                      False  False  True                    False  False  False                         False  False  False
```

Now I want to know, for every unique pair of `start` and `end`, what is total count of `True` for `LT`, `MA` and `PL`. So my final Dataframe should look like

```
start         end           LT  MA  PL
10.10.80.10   10.55.10.1    0   1   1
10.100.80.10  10.55.10.1    0   0   1
12.100.90.10  100.100.12.1  1   0   1
```

I just can't seem to figure out how do I extract the required information from the cross tab.

Comment: why is `LT` value `1` for the row `12.100.90.10  100.100.12.1 `? I guess it should probably be `3`.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma I am counting total occurrences of `True` for each case. If you refer to the previous Dataframe (right above it), `LT` for the pair `12.100.90.10  100.100.12.1` contains one `True`. Hence total count of `True` is 1.

Comment: I'm really not sure how you got the boolean values in the dataframe ..Maybe you can try @anky 's answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the same solution you are referring to and sum, and unstack along last axis:

```
pd.crosstab(
       index=df['date'].dt.floor('1min'), 
       columns=[
           df['start'], 
           df['end'], 
           df['type'].str.extract(r'(\w+)_', expand=False)
      ], 
    ).astype(bool).sum().unstack(-1, fill_value=0)

type                       LT  MA  PL
start        end                     
10.10.80.10  10.55.10.1     0   1   1
10.100.80.10 10.55.10.1     0   0   1
12.100.90.10 100.100.12.1   1   0   1
```

Comment: hi! thanks for getting back to my problem. I tried your solution but it seems your result is wrong if I change the data that is expected to give a count of 2 for `LT` for the pair `12.100.90.10 100.100.12.1`. Here is the detailed explanation https://codeshare.io/24Z7JK I think you are missing out on the `.dt.floor('1min')` which you had done in your earlier cross tab and that gave the correct count.

Comment: @SouvikRay I see, I think I understand now. Check the edit, if it works.

Comment: thanks mate! This is finally what I wanted. Thank you again for taking out your time to help me. I really appreciate it!